# Shock anziché scioccante

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, nouns

Pensavo fosse un vezzo dei giornalisti del gossip l’uso del sostantivo “shock” come aggettivo. Ad esempio:

- [Barbara d’Urso annuncia una notizia shock](https://www.lanostratv.it/2020/12/barbara-durso-annuncia-una-notizia-shock-su-pietro-delle-piane-e-grave/) .
- [Scandalo da Maria De Filippi, la confessione shock](https://www.kontrokultura.it/230106/scandalo-da-maria-de-filippi-la-confessione-shock-siamo-andati-a-letto-insieme-poi-mi-ha-scaricato/amp/).

ma in realtà l’uso aggettivale di “shock”  mi sembra si stia diffondendo anche sulle notizie di cronaca e politica:

- [Ndrangheta, intercettazioni shock:](https://video.gazzettadireggio.gelocal.it/locale/ndrangheta-intercettazioni-shock-c-e-da-picchiare-una-donna-buttatele-l-acido-in-faccia/136513/137082)
- [Arresto shock in Usa, manette e spray al peperoncino su bimba di 9 anni](https://www.adnkronos.com/arresto-shock-in-usa-manette-e-spray-al-peperoncino-su-bimba-di-9-anni_7tSkFKfyCBlbpTI8Pck5Xt)

Non mi risulta che [shock](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/shock/)  sia un aggettivo, ma probabilmente “scioccante” è troppo lungo e di minore effetto.

Mi chiedo se questo uso sia recente e se di fatto sia un trend che, forse, dovrà essere registrato da qualche dizionario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effetti, il [Supplemento del 2009 al *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_755.jpg) lo registra come aggettivo con il significato di "scioccante e sensazionalistico", con la marca *NA* (immagino che *N* stia per neologismo). Dà come prima attestazione un articolo del *Corriere della Sera* del 20-VIII-1993. Eccone la citazione riportata in questo vocabolario:

> Notizia shock per l’economia americana: il deficit commerciale con l’estero, ricorrente incubo degli anni Ottanta, torna a salire prepotentemente.

Sul Supplemento sopra menzionato si trova anche un'altra occorrenza, in cui mi sembra curioso l'uso della maiuscola iniziale:

> *La Stampa* [15-II-2006]: Iraq: video Shock, cecchino spara contro soldati Usa.

Dagli esempi sopra riportati e da quelli della domanda, questo uso di *shock* sembra essersi diffuso nell'ambito giornalistico.

Comment: Interessante, quindi l’uso sembra essersi diffuso prima nella stampa regolare e non in quella scandalistica.